# Couchbase error : Authentication failed when querying a protected bucket Nodejs

Tags: node.js, couchbase

Below is my sample code to query a pass protected bucket in couchbase in nodejs

```
var couchbase = require("couchbase");
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster("couchbase://127.0.0.1");
var N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('bucketname', 'Admin123');
var  q = N1qlQuery.fromString('SELECT * FROM `bucketname`');
var  req = bucket.query(q);
req.on('row',  function (row) {    
    console.log('Got a row');
});
req.on('error',  function (err) {    
    console.error('Got error %j',  err);
    process.exit(0);
});
req.on('end',  function (meta) {    
    console.log('All rows received. Metadata is %j:',  meta);
    process.exit(0);
});
```

getting: 
 
       **CouchbaseError: Authentication failed. You may have provided an invalid username/password combination**

Answer (score 0):

If using Cloudbase 5.0, Role-based access control (RBAC) for users and applications was integrated.

You should authenticate with the admin user or a user you created.

Then, do not forget the call to cluster.authenticate, as explained there : https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/sdk/nodejs/start-using-sdk.html

```
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster("couchbase://127.0.0.1");
cluster.authenticate(‘USERNAME’, ‘PASSWORD’);
var N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('bucketname');
```

Answer (score -1):

`Admin123` looks like the root password. You have to provide the password for the specific bucket. Create a password for the `bucketname` bucket in the admin UI and pass this password.

If you didn't set it up, it might be blank, so

```
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('bucketname','');
```

might work for you.

Comment: root pass is different...I'm able to GET using key i've but unable to perform   QUERY

Comment: Could you confirm that you created a bucket with name 'bucketname' and password 'admin123' ? Does your code work if you remove the password from the bucket?